# Python list from csv line and write list to file

Tags: python

I'm new to python and no prior experience at all.
I have a requirement to convert a file contains a single line as: `abc,def,ghi,jkl`, to another file which should have the values from the above line as below:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

I've tried as below but receives error say that `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
inputFile = 'servers'
outputFile = 'cservers'
serverList = []
with open(inputFile) as fi, open(outputFile,'w') as fo:
  line = fi.readline()
  serverList.append(line.split(','))
for i in serverList:
  fo.write(i+'\n')
```

What is wrong with above code?

Thanks

Comment: `i` is a list of lists. If you want it to be a list of strings, probably do `serverList.extend(line.split(','))`.  Think about what happens if `split` returns a list. (Hint: it always does.)

Comment: Understood now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` returns a list, not a string. After the line `serverList.append(..)`, the variable `serverList` is a list conataining a list that contains strings, looks something like that: [['abc', 'def', ...]].

So serverList is a list of lists, with one element. Then you iterate through serverList (remember, there is only one element) and the element is a list. You try to add '\n' to a list, which is an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`. Generally, use the error you receive to see what wrong: it says you are tried to add string with a list.

To fix it, just use

```py
serverList = line.split(',')
```

Then the whole list returns for `split` commands will be in serverList inside of an element within it

Edit: as mentioned in comments, this will handle only one line of input - but from what I understand, that is okay for you (as you also read only one line). If you want to iterate through lines in the future, you can use `serverList = serverList + line.split(',')` which adds two lists together

Comment: This will only handle a single line of input, and overwrite the `serverList` on each iteration over the file.

Comment: I know, but he only has one line anyway. I added an edit to clarify that, thanks

Comment: Yes, its clear now. Currently there is only one line. Thank you for the explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

In your example the line

```py
    serverList.append(line.split(','))
```

results in a `serverList` that looks like `[['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']]`. So when you come to execute

```py
    fo.write(i+'\n')
```

You will get a `TypeError` thrown for the reason given in the console output.

You can test this by running.

```py
a = [['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']]
print(a+'\n')
```

You could fix your code by changing your code so that `serverList` is a list of strings representing lines to be written to `outputFile` as opposed to a list containing a list of strings. See below for example solution.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
inputFile = 'servers'
outputFile = 'cservers'

with open(inputFile) as fi:
    serverList = fi.read().split(',') # Read file contents as list of strings delimited by comma in file

with open(outputFile,'w') as fo:
    fo.writelines(s + '\n' for s in serverList) # Write each string in serverList on own line
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the split() function it returns a list

So your list named serverList now contains another list.

Now this code here:

```
for i in serverList:
  fo.write(i+'\n')
```

Means you're looping through the serverList and remember that each element of this list is another list.

So that is the reason for the error. Because here in your code:

```
+'\n'
```

You are trying to concatenate (join) a list with a string which is not possible.